# Why does my dialog controller fail after minification?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code which works fine un-minimised:

```
$scope.newContact = function(ev) {
    console.log(1);
    var d = $dialog.dialog({
        template : newcontactdialog, 
        controller : 'ContactDialogController'
     });
console.log(2);
d.open().then(function(result) {
   console.log(4);
});
console.log(3);
};

function ContactDialogController($scope, dialog) { ... etc ...}
```

After I minimise (closure compiler, Simple Optimizations), I get:

```
1
2
3
Error: Unknown provider: aProvider <- a
```

I guess I need to do something to protect the `ContactDialogController`, or perhaps it's the  `($scope, dialog)` function arguments, but I can't figure it out.

Is there a recommended minifier for AngularJS?

Comment: See **A Note on Minification** of the [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mvc4 bundling, minification and AngularJS services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909541/mvc4-bundling-minification-and-angularjs-services)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the controller in this format:

```
var PhoneListCtrl = ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { /* constructor body */ }];
```

Check out 'A Note on Minification' from the [angular tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05).

Comment: sure. I meant to do it straight away, but SO forced me to wait