# AngularJs Uncaught Error when deployed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, azure-cloud-services

I am seeing this error in AngularJS

[image]

Wierdly, it only occurs when I deploy it in Azure Cloud.

In my local instance - it doesn't occur.

Any ideas?

Update: this is the [actual website](http://tradies-prototype.cloudapp.net/)

login using this sample account

sample@test.com / 1Sample

UPDATE! I suspect that this script causes the error

[image]

I dont know why the select.js fails to minify

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

I actually installed the ui-select via bower command line - and then just include it manualy in the bundleconfig. Is this the issue here?

UPDATE - I pinpoint the error and seems like the config of the ui-select is the culprit

[image]

Any idea on this?

Comment: Can you post the link provided in the stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because it's getting a 404 error for this resource:

```
http://tradies-prototype.cloudapp.net/bundles/angular-animate.min.js.map
```

Make sure to include the `.map` files in your bundle.

**EDIT**:

As @CaspNZ pointed out in the comments bellow, if you have a look at this:

http://tradies-prototype.cloudapp.net/bundles/angular

you will see that you are getting this error:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(248,386-393): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break a
 */
```

Which means that there is something wrong with your ASP.Net MVC Bundling. It could be many things, but make sure that you are aware of [**this**](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification), so that your angularJs code can be minified properly.

**EDIT 2**

Also, have a look at this: [Mvc4 bundling, minification and AngularJS services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909541/mvc4-bundling-minification-and-angularjs-services) and this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/786205/ASP-NET-MVC-bundling-minification-with-angularjs-a

Comment: Unrelated to this, it looks like minification failed: /* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(248,386-393): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break a
 */

Comment: yeah i dont think thats the problem - i have another site that gives that error but the site is still running!

Comment: @CaspNZ actually I think that it must be related, he must be using ASP.NET MVC Bundling and it must be crashing, maybe that's why the .map files are not available.

Comment: hah. Nice. How did you identify the 404 error? I can't find a reference to it.

Comment: yeah worth a try - ill include the .map and we'll see.

Comment: @LincAbela it's VERY obvious that your problem is with the  ASP.NET MVC Bundling, that's why you only have this issue in production (when it tries to minify) and not in the dev environemnt

Comment: theinclusion .map file doesnt resolve the issue - is there any quickway to debug what file is failing to minify? i basically have hundreds of file bundled

Comment: this doesnt give me any info what file are failing http://fbc38b33aa394da5a7b8fd642371f931.cloudapp.net/bundles/angular?v=uhdbMsYHeDKxwoWldbA40ueg9PLrJdldQsJ-JMKykWs1

Comment: @LincAbela in your bundle: are you using the already minified version of angular (angular.min.js)? If you are, I would try to use the non minified ones. Also: have you had a look at the links of my answer?

Comment: @LincAbela it seems to me that the minification is failing for you 'angular' bundle, there shouldn't be so many files in that bundle, right?

Comment: Yeah sees like it... when i remove the reference to https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select, the error doesnt occur!

Comment: im trying to reference the select.js (see here http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview). I think the js is failing

Comment: @LincAbela if I go here: http://tradies-prototype.cloudapp.net/bundles/angular and I do a search for 'ui.select' I get nothing... Which means that the 'select.js' files is not getting included in your bundle... Why? I have no idea! In a few hours I will be in my real computer, where I have VS2013 and I will try to get that file bundled and see what happens... But at least we have been able to figure out what's causing the issue.

Comment: yeah seems like it is the issue - i added the file using bower - if I reference the file using bower, im getting wierd errors. thanks