# How to find what causes [$injector:modulerr] error in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

But I do not remember what I did wrong, so how can I find what causes this error?

**JS**:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(function($mdIconProvider) {
    $mdIconProvider
        .defaultFontSet( 'fontawesome' )
        .iconSet("call", '/images/icons/sets/communication-icons.svg', 24)
        .iconSet("social", '/images/icons/sets/social-icons.svg', 24);
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $mdUtil, $log) {
    $scope.toggleLeft = buildToggler('left');
    $scope.toggleRight = buildToggler('right');
    /**
     * Build handler to open/close a SideNav; when animation finishes
     * report completion in console
     **/
    function buildToggler(navID) {
        var debounceFn =  $mdUtil.debounce(function(){
            $mdSidenav(navID)
                .toggle()
                .then(function () {
                    $log.debug("toggle " + navID + " is done");
                });
        },200);
        return debounceFn;
    }
    $scope.closeLeft = function () {
        $mdSidenav('left').close()
        .then(function () {
            $log.debug("close LEFT is done");
        });
    };
    $scope.closeRight = function () {
        $mdSidenav('right').close()
        .then(function () {
            $log.debug("close RIGHT is done");
        });
    };

    var originatorEv;
    this.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
        originatorEv = ev;
        $mdOpenMenu(ev);
    };
});


function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
    };
    $scope.answer = function(answer) {
        $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };
}
```

ps. I do not use `ngRoute` in my App if that is the cause of the error.

Comment: if you can use non minified angular - you can get more readable error message

Comment: Have you included all required js files in html? Make sure that no js file missed to include...

Comment: do you minify your code? or use it as is?

Comment: @Grundy I have all js minified. I will try to use unminified files.

Comment: see a bit about injections in doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#argument-names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mvc4 bundling, minification and AngularJS services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909541/mvc4-bundling-minification-and-angularjs-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use an unminified version of Angular to get better error handling.

Also I always recommend using strict dependency injection like so:

```
.config(['$mdIconProvider', function($mdIconProvider) {
....
]);
```

Comment: methinks, you find solution if user minify his code :-)

Comment: Sorry how do you mean? 
I meant because in the error message it says angular.min.js he should go for angular.js unminified in a dev environment.

Comment: @MoBinni Thank you so much! I will try to use unminified version of Angular.

Comment: My pleasure :) happy to help, hit me up if you have any Angular-specific questions.

Comment: i mean, if OP minify own code, after minification angular can't inject service, and raise error, ofcourse if not injected manually

Comment: Yeah you're right, that would work, but don't you think it's easier in development to work off unminified code.

Comment: @MoBinni, if use approach OP, whithout annotation, so in dev code all would work, and in prod - error :-) Because problem not in angular version, but in OP code

Comment: I didnt specify it was the angular version tho just the type ^^ but ur right it would work that way, I just find it more useful to run unminified in dev